# How to add a dynamic field on the Navigation Key URL in Oracle CC&B?

Tags: configuration, oracle-ccb

We are working with Oracle CC&B (Customer Care & Billing), and we have a couple of Navigation Keys we use on "Favorite Links" for all our users. We are trying to add a new one, but this time the URL has a dynamic field.

So far, we have tried providing ACCT_ID as a Context Field in the Navigation Option. But it's not passing the value of ACCT_ID to the URL.

How do we pass the value of the context field from the Navigation Option to the external URL in the Navigation Key?

Answer (score 1):

Navigation Option setting

1. Nav Opt Type = Transaction
2. Nav Mode set Change
3. Usage set Favorites
4. Target Transaction set Point to Nav Key - External/URL
5. Context Field (under Nav Option) 
      -Add ACCT_ID + KEY FIELD = Y
   (also supports PER_ID & PREM_ID if loaded  on dashboard)`

Flush All/system login Info

Pull up an account and then click your Fav URL it will append ?ACCT_ID=11111111
https://XXXX.X-XXX.net/XXX/default.asp?ACCT_ID=11111111

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I realize now where our issue is. We are trying to use a field other than ACCT_ID, PREM_ID, and PER_ID. We will explore adding another context field and see how it goes. Thanks again.